# How to anonymously join public events?

Tags: facebook, privacy, calendar, anonymous

How can I join an event without having my name listed? Below I can see everyone's name, almost all of which I don't know, except for Facebook User's.

[image: Facebook user event details]
<sub>Names of attendees for event on public page that I **Like**.</sub>

How can I be *that* guy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to hide your name from the list. Event host can change privacy setting for the event but in that case also your name will be visible to selected audience.

What you can do is you can remove yourself from the list.

Comment: Is that how this person shows up as "Facebook User"?

Comment: This person means which person?

Comment: The person who appears as "Facebook User" (see the Maybe section). I'm pretty certain that's not just a name he typed in to sign up. I've seen several events before this that got me thinking this was possible, since some of them had many people identified as "Facebook User"

Comment: "Facebook User" means user has deleted that account or Facebook closed that account.